# How do I store a cookie after login

Tags: c#, post, cookies

I'm trying to sign in to a website. It should be done by a POST request. But i need to store the cookie somehow.

My actual code:

```
 public void botLogin(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string post_data = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(post_data);

        var requestUri = "http://registration.zwinky.com/registration/loginAjax.jhtml";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        var sharedCookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = sharedCookies;

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

        sr.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
```

How would i store the cookie now to use it for other requests?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, cast the created WebRequest to HttpWebRequest. This will give you access to more HTTP-specific properties and methods.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
```

Define a CookieContainer object at the application level and set that for each created request.

```
request.CookieContainer = sharedCookies;
```

I'm pretty sure, the HttpWebRequest object will store the cookies after the download so that the next request can use them. If that still doesn't work, examine the HttpWebResponse object for cookies (again, don't forget to cast the response object to that).

Comment: The function is updated in the upper code now. How would i call this cookie now from other methods?

Comment: As mentionned by christoph, the botlogin procedure should use a class variable for the cookie container (or return it in an out parameter). You may also define the HttpWebRequest as a class variable and use it for subsequent requests. --- Warning: pay attention to eventual auto-redirections that don't keep cookies provided by redirected Url.